# Consume External API in Laravel with Guzzle and Save into the Database

Tags: laravel, api, guzzle

I am using Laravel-5.8 in my server. I have this external endpoint given to me which I cannot alter:

https://api.studklm.net/students/allstudents

It is a GET Request and in JSON (application/json) format.

```
[
  {
    "Student Code": "S001",
    "Full Name": "Adeleke Omowale",
    "StudentClass": "JSS 1",
    "AcademicTerm": "First"
  },
    "Student Code": "S002",
    "Full Name": "James Smith",
    "StudentClass": "JSS 1",
    "AcademicTerm": "First"
  },
    "Student Code": "S003",
    "Full Name": "Haruna Muri",
    "StudentClass": JSS 2",
    "AcademicTerm": "First"
  }
]
```

Then, in my server I have this table:

```
 CREATE TABLE `students` (
`id` int NOT NULL auto_increment,
`registration_no` varchar(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
`full_name` varchar(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
`student_class` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`academic_term` varchar(255) NOT NULL

) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I am writing a cron job that will save an external api into my database using Guzzle.

I checked the site below to read some information, but I got stuck along the way.

https://appdividend.com/2018/04/17/laravel-guzzle-http-client-example/

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;


use App\Student;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException;
use GuzzleHttp;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class studentdataupdate extends Command {

 protected $signature = 'command:studentdataupdate';
 protected $description = 'Student Data Update';
 public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

 public function handle() {  
 $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
 $res = $client->request('GET','https://api.studklm.net/students/allstudents');

        return $result->getBody(); 

        $clients = json_decode($result, true);

        foreach($clients as $client) {
            Student::updateOrCreate([
                'registration_no' => $client->Student Code,
                'full_name' => $client->Full Name,
                'student_class' => $client->StudentClass,
                'facademic_term' => $client->AcademicTerm
            ]);
        }              
    }
}
```

I want to achieve these results:

1. registration_no and full_name are unique, and should not allow duplicates
2. Some of the fields from the external api are not well formatted, there are spaces in between. For instance, **Full Name** and **Student Code**. How do I resolve this while trying to save into my database without error?
3. If **Full Name** or **Student Code** already exists, it updates. Else, it inserts the new record.

Comment: why do you have this `return $result->getBody(); `

Comment: How about if using student code as id? So, make it unique id using string as a primary key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of easy fixes for your `updateOrCreate()` method that may help you toward a solution.

First, you can pass strings as attributes in PHP by using curly braces.  This comes in handy when there are issues like spaces, or you want to dynamically pass a variable with a string value.

```php
// $client->{$string}
$client->{'Full Name'}
```

Second, `updateOrCreate()` accepts not one, but two arrays.  The first is used to search for existing entries.  The following example would update the database if the `registration_no` matches an existing entry, or create a new entry if not.

```php
Student::updateOrCreate([
    'registration_no' => $client->{'Student Code'},
    // 'full_name' => $client->{'Full Name'}, // uncomment to use both
],
[
    'full_name' => $client->{'Full Name'}, // not required if uncommented above
    'student_class' => $client->StudentClass,
    'facademic_term' => $client->AcademicTerm
]);
```

**EDIT:**
If you want to do `registration_no` OR `full_name`, you may have to search the values manually before updating, as `updateOrCreate()` uses an AND condition for searching when multiple fields are present.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a cron job for Laravel schedule

`crontab -e`

`* * * * * cd /[path-to-your-laravel-project] && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

2. Add your console command to console/kernel.php

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
     $schedule->command('command:studentdataupdate')->everyMinute(); 
}
```